# Normal Switch and LAN9353

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, ethernet, phy

I am reading about the different types of LAN Switches.

And I came across the LAN9353 device - [Link](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9353)

I want to understand the difference between a normal Gigabit Ethernet 3 port switch and this LAN9353 device?

I went through the datasheet and saw that it supports Turbo MII and there are other features. And I read this in the General Description section, Page 8,

"The LAN9353 provides 2 on-chip PHYs, 2 Virtual PHYs and 3 MACs. The Virtual PHY and the third MAC are used to connect the Switch Fabric to an external MAC or PHY. In MAC mode, the device can be connected to an external PHY via the MII/RMII/Turbo MII interface."

So, LAN9353 supports 3 MAC ports? And what is Turbo MII?

Comment: Have you looked at the block diagrams how the device can be used and searched for the text "turbo" to find out what it means?

Comment: Ask yourself what an ethernet switch is supposed to do and how does it work? Just from the description I can surmise that basically the device can either be used standalone by the addition of an external phy or connected to a processor with a MAC. I could be totally wrong as I've not read the datasheet but based on what you'd expect such a chip to do, I'm probably close. It operates probably much the same as a 3 port switch you'd buy from a computer shop.

Comment: I looked at the block diagrams. But I am unable to get good clarity.. Still confusing